# Failed to convert parameter value -- Updating changes to a DataGridView

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to update a SQL Server database when the user modifies a cell in a DataGridView on a Windows Form. I get the error

```
Failed to convert parameter value from a DataGridViewTextBoxCell to a String
```

on the line 'update.ExecuteNonQuery()'. I'm running Visual Studio C# Express 2008 and SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 R2. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the UpdateCommand.
        SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(
            "UPDATE clients SET " +
            "client_name_first = @client_name_first " +
            "WHERE client_id = @modifiedRowNum;", connect);

        // Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
        update.Parameters.Add(
            "@client_name_first", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
            dgvClients.Rows[dgvClients.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1].Cells[dgvClients.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];            
        update.Parameters.Add(
            "@modifiedRowNum", SqlDbType.Int, 5).Value = dgvClients.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1;            

        // Execute the operation.
        update.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurred because you have not specified `.Value` property after `Cell`. You are trying to assign `DataGridViewCell` instead of value of that cell. The value can be retrieved from cell by using `.Value` property.

ie. `var value = dgv.Rows[RowIndex].Cell[ColumnIndex].Value`.

and in the code you just need to add `.Value` after `..Cells[dgvClients.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex]`

```
update.Parameters.Add("@client_name_first", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = dgvClients.Rows[dgvClients.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1].Cells[dgvClients.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value;
```

the complete code will be look like this

```
// Create the UpdateCommand.
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(
        "UPDATE clients SET " +
        "client_name_first = @client_name_first " +
        "WHERE client_id = @modifiedRowNum;", connect);

// Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
update.Parameters.Add(
        "@client_name_first", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
        dgvClients.Rows[dgvClients.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1].Cells[dgvClients.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value;            
update.Parameters.Add(
        "@modifiedRowNum", SqlDbType.Int, 5).Value = dgvClients.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1;            

// Execute the operation.
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
```